# The constructor JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf, Duration) is undefined

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Below is my code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));
```

Its throwing below error:

> The constructor JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf, Duration) is undefined

But when I see Spark guide am able to see below

```
JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf conf, Duration batchDuration)
```

Create a `JavaStreamingContext` using a SparkConf configuration.

Why is it showing error when I use the above constructor?

Comment: Usually means a version mismatch.

Comment: Check the imports and make sure the `SparkConf` and `Duration` classes in your code match the ones in the Spark guide.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are confusing

`org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration` with other `Duration` class

Constructor of JavaStreamingContext expects `org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration`

```
public JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf conf,
                    Duration batchDuration)
```

Make sure you are passing the correct parameters. Also always check StackTrace it helps a lot